# Is there a reliable way to know what libraries could be dlopen()ed in an elf binary?

Tags: c, posix, gnu, elf

Basically, I want to get a list of libraries a binary might load.

The unreliable way I came up with that seems to work (with possible false-positives):

```
comm -13 <(ldd elf_file | sed 's|\s*\([^ ]*\)\s.*|\1|'| sort -u) <(strings -a elf_file | egrep '^(|.*/)lib[^:/]*\.so(|\.[0-9]+)$' | sort -u)
```

This is not reliable. But it gives useful information, even if the binary was stripped.

Is there a reliable way to get this information without possible false-positives?

**EDIT**: More context.

Firefox is transitioning from using `gstreamer` to using `ffmpeg`.
I was wondering what versions of `libavcodec.so` will work.
`libxul.so` uses `dlopen()` for many optional features.
And the library names are hard-coded. So, the above command helps
in this case.

I also have a general interest in package management and binary dependencies.
I know you can get direct dependencies with `readelf -d`, dependencies of
dependencies with `ldd`. And I was wondering about optional dependencies, hence the question.

Comment: Names of libraries that get `dlopen()`d do not have to appear in `ldd`s output.

Comment: What if I `dlopen(argv[i])`? How will you find out?

Comment: Also, `dlopen()`ed modules do not have to have names beginning with "lib".  Nor even, I guess, ending with ".so".

Comment: Here's a pretty reliable way: `find / |xargs file |grep 'ELF .* shared object'`

Comment: @nwellnhof: what if the shared object is downloaded on the fly? :-)

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? What is the particular binary whose potential plugins you want to list?

Comment: @NotImportant: for such questions, the first thing to think about is: it the question equivalent to the halting problem (and my answer explains that it is).

Comment: I finally downvoted the question, since the OP did not improve it by **editing the question** to explain why is he asking, and what particular binary is he concerned with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ldd` tells you the libraries your binary has been linked against. These are not those that the program *could* open with `dlopen`.

The signature for `dlopen` is

```
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);
```

So you could, *still unreliably*, run `strings` on the binary, but this could still fail if the library name is not a static string, but built or read from somewhere during program execution -- and this last situation means that the answer to your question is "no"... Not reliably. (The name of the library file could be read from the network, from a Unix socket, or even uncompressed on the fly, for example. Anything is possible! -- although I wouldn't recommend any of these ideas myself...)

**edit**: also, as John Bollinger mentioned, the library names could be read from a config file.

**edit**: you could also try substituting the `dlopen` system call with one of yours (this is done by the [Boehm](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) garbage collector with `malloc`, for example), so it would open the library, but also log its name somewhere. But if the program didn't open a specific library during execution, you still won't know about it.

Comment: More common and reasonable is for loadable module names to be read from a configuration file.  My guess would be that it is most common to `dlopen()` modules whose names do *not* appear as literal strings in the binary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, assuming the library names are hard-coded, `strings` is our best bit, right?

Comment: Regarding your second edit: 1- It requires execution which kind of defeats the purpose since we can trace the running process anyway. 2- There is no guaranty we well run through all code paths where dlopen() is called.

Comment: @Not Important: yes, I mentioned that <if the program didn't open a specific library during execution, you still won't know about it> -- so not all code paths would be covered.

Comment: @Not Important: `strings` is a possibility. Trying to find config files and tracing the program may help a lot too!

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux; I guess that most of my answer fits for every POSIX systems; but on MacOSX `dlopen` wants `.dylib` [dynamic library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) files, not `.so` shared objects)</sup>

A program could even emit some C code in some temporary file `/tmp/foo1234.c`, `fork` a compilation of that `/tmp/foo1234.c`  into a shared library `/tmp/foo1234.so` by some `gcc -O -shared -fPIC /tmp/foo1234.c -o /tmp/foo1234.so` command -generated and executed at runtime of your program-, perhaps remove the `/tmp/foo1234.c` file -since it is not needed any more-, and `dlopen` that `/tmp/foo1234.so` (and perhaps even remove `/tmp/foo1234.so` after `dlopen`), all that in the same process. My [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) plugin for `gcc`  does exactly this, and so does [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/), and the [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) library is doing something close.

So in general, your quest is impossible and even has no sense.

> Is there a reliable way to get this information without possible false-positives?

**No, there is no reliable way to get such information** without false positives (you could prove that equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), or to some other [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)). See also [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem).

In practice, most `dlopen` happens on plugins provided by some configuration. There might not be exactly named as such in a configuration file (e.g. some `Foo` programs might have a convention like a plugin named `bar` in some `foo.conf` configuration file is provided by `foo-bar.so` plugin).

However, you might find some *heuristic* approximation. Most programs doing some `dlopen` have some plugin *convention* requesting some particular *symbol names* in the plugin. You could search for shared objects defining these names. Of course you'll get false positives.

For example, the [zsh](http://zsh.org/) shell accepts plugins called [zsh modules](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html). the [example](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/Modules/example.c) module shows that `enables_`, 
`boot_`, `features_` etc... functions are expected in zsh modules. You could use `nm -D` to find `*.so` files providing these (hence finding the plugins *likely* to be *perhaps* loadable by `zsh`)

<sup>(I am not convinced that such an approach is worthwhile; in fact you should usually know which plugins are useful on *your* system by which applications)</sup>

BTW, you could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on the execution of some command to understand the syscalls it is doing, hence the plugins it is loading. You might also use [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), or [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) (on some given process), or simply -for a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) 1234- use `cat /proc/1234/maps` to understand its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), hence the plugins it has *already* loaded. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Notice that `strace`, `ltrace`, `pmap` exist on Linux, but many POSIX systems have *similar* programs.

Also, a program could generate some machine code at runtime and execute it ([SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) does that at *every* [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction!). Your program could also use some [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques (e.g. with [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [llvm](http://llvm.org/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or with hand-written code...) to do likewise. So plugin-like behavior can happen without `dlopen`  (and you might mimic `dlopen` with `mmap` calls and some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) relocation processing).

---

#### Addenda:

If you are installing firefox from its packaged version (e.g. the `iceweasel`  package on Debian), its package is likely to handle the dependencies

Comment: I believe the program could even delete the `.so` file after `dlopen()`-ing it, no? Or does POSIX require, even implicitly, that the `.so` file remain available after `dlopen()`?

Comment: @Jay: you are right. The `.so` file could even be deleted after `dlopen`. But `/proc/1234/maps` would show something about it.